# How does Scriptella perform in comparison to SQLLoader when utilized for Oracle?

Tags: etl, sql-loader, oracle11gr2, scriptella

I'm hoping that some of you out there with experience using both Scriptella and Oracle SQL*Loader can help me determine if speed and performance are comparable for these two data loading solutions.

I am very interested in Scriptella for its wide variety in ETL functionality and scripting flexibility. My primary concern is that I may be sacrificing performance for features if I decide to forego SQL*Loader in favor of Scriptella.

Has anyone attempted to compare these two? If so what are the results?